# Wide characters in lcurses

Tags: lua, ncurses, luajit

While getting into programming with *lcurses* in Lua I've noticed that the same code runs differently on *lua* and *luajit* (given the source is stored in UTF-8):

```
local locale = os.setlocale('')
require 'curses'

curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.echo(0)
curses.nl(0)

local stdscr = curses.stdscr()
stdscr:clear()
stdscr:mvaddstr(0,0,'--->English,')
stdscr:mvaddstr(1,0,'--->Español')
stdscr:mvaddstr(2,0,'--->Русский (Russian)')
stdscr:mvaddstr(3,0,'--->日本語 (Japanese)')
stdscr:refresh()

stdscr:getch()
curses.endwin()

print(locale)
```

While running on *luajit* everything is printed as expected, but on plain *lua* every UTF-8 character gets turned into strange-looking sequence:

```
--->English,
--->EspaM-CM-1ol
--->M-PM- M-Q~CM-Q~AM-Q~AM-PM-:M-PM-8M-PM-9 (Russian)
--->M-f~WM-%M-f~\M-,M-hM-*~^ (Japanese)
```

This was run under Linux in UTF-8 aware console with en_US.UTF-8 locale. Also I've looked into *curses.so* which comes with *lcurses* rock and found that it is using right *ncurses* library (with wide characters support):

```
$ readelf -a curses.so | grep NEEDED
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libncursesw.so.5]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Software versions:

- lua 5.1.4
- luajit 2.0.0 beta7
- ncurses 5.9
- lcurses 6-2 (installed from luarocks)

**Edit:**

The question itself, which I've forgotten to write from the very beginning:

- Does anybody know why this happen?
- How to make it work in plain lua?

Comment: Debugging time! Source -> Lua -> lcurses -> libraries and system. To eliminate the source and Lua, do this in LuaJIT and Lua: `i=0 for c in("Русский"):gmatch'.'do i=i+string.byte(c) end print(i)`. If the results vary, then Lua is dealing with encodings improbably. To eliminate lcurses, try doing using a `set`/`get` pair: `v='Русский'c=curses.new_chstr(#v+1)c:set(0,v)print(c:get(0))`. If that doesn't come out as expected, it's a problem in lcurses, probably with the Lua API. Worst case is lcurses<->system going wrong. Any info will help us help you help us all!

Comment: @Deco, I've tested your "one-liners". The first one gave the same result (2563) for both lua and luajit. But the second one doesn't seem to work at all: lua/luajit tells there is no functions get and set defined.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Lua only handles ASCII characters. Strings can contain non-ASCII, but Lua doesn't know how to print them. LuaJIT has [special extensions](http://luajit.org/extensions.html) to be able to handle UTF-8 strings.

Comment: I know it. But at least lua strings can store arbitrary byte sequence (in my case it is UTF-8 encoded text). As lcurses are just a thin wrapper to ncurses functions, they should work fine even without lua support. But it works in luajit and do *not* work in plain lua. The question is "Why?".

Comment: @firegurafiku: Because Lua and LuaJIT are not the same. There is no Lua "standard" that the main-line Lua and LuaJIT both implement or something. There simply Lua's behavior and LuaJIT tries to ape that behavior to some extent. As I said, LuaJIT has special code for handling UTF-8 in various situations, which Lua *does not*.

Comment: What kind of special code is required to pass char* to the underlying function? ncursesw can handle UTF-8 without support on the level of lua. I think it is something wrong with setlocale() in plain lua.

Answer (score 0):

To use raw utf-8 text just add one line at the beginning of your program:

```
os.setlocale('')
```

Comment: Sorry, now I see it. It works for me. Try `LANG='' curses_lua`